# MVC 4 normal area routing admin area automatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have these routes

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {area="", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "WebControllers.Controllers" });

  routes.MapRoute(
           "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {Area="Admin", Controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
          new[] { "WebControllers.Areas.Admin.Controllers" });
```

I have Users controller on admin area. When I try to reach /admin/users it's ok.
But even I don't have users controller on normal area (""), /users routes to /admin/users controller but it can't find view and gives error.

How can I prevent /users path routes to /admin/users ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure I totally understand the question, but I believe the solution will be to change the order of your MapRoute calls. You should add routes by order of how specific they are.

for instance, if you add routes in this order

```
 {controller}/{action}/{id}
 Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

Any url that matches controller/action/id will be matched and routed. The second route will never be used.

If, however, you swap the order, mvc will match Admin/controller/action/id first. Essentially routing will stop checking for matches after the first one that works.